# Android: How do i delete a non authorized user in cognito?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

So i have this confirm activity. In the activity i have two buttons (submit & resend code). You press the submit button when you typed in the code you got via email or phone number through cognito. And you press "resend" when you have not received any code and would cognito to resend the verification code.

Question:

Is there a line of code to resend a verification code to aws cognito via android?

If not:

currently, i have this line of code:

```
cognitoUser.deleteUser(handler);
```

And then, I would recreate the user in cognito.

```
  userPool.signUpInBackground(username, password, userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
```

But the exception that it throws when i try to delete user, is that the `user is not authorized`. So i cannot delete the user.

How do i handle the "resend code"? A reference to a documentation or the line(s) of code would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to resend the confirmation code (if we are talking about the signup confirmation code) by calling resendConfirmationCodeInBackground on a cognitoUser

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/8957e9402cf7490bfa9c3939eabc92f1b7d4572e/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo/app/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/youruserpools/SignUpConfirm.java#L199

deleteUser is an authenticated operation so you would need to authenticate the user first before calling deleteUser.

If you are talking about an attribute verification code, calling getUserAttributeVerificationCode would send the code and verifyUserAttribute would verify the sent code.